# Not able to perform operation with mongoose on db collection with few conditions

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm Using Mongoose for Mongo db. I want to perform some operations. Not able to get the results.

I have a collection USERS with schema like:

```
{username: 'user1', id: 1, lastName: 'ln1' }
{username: 'user2', id: 0, lastName: 'ln2' }
```

Id can be 0,1,2 or 3

I want to enter a new object with these conditons:

- If username exists and id is 1 then Update the details.
- If username doesnot exist then create a new entry no need to check for id.
- If username exists and id is 0,2 or 3 (other than 1) then do nothing (do not update or enter the user in collection ) and keep the value that this user as it failed to enter in the db.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used promise library but you can also use callbacks

Assumption : You want to work on User model

```
 User.findOne({username:"USERNAME"}).exec()
    .then((result)=>{
      if(result){
          if(result.id == 1){
         //update result object and then save it
           result.lastName="abc";
           result.save(); // it will update your result
            }else{
           console.log('failed to enter in the db.')  
           }
        }else{
          User(userObject).save(); // it will create new entry
        }

})
```